# remove a single character between 2 divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I've got a nasty little character stuck between 2 divs:

```
<div id="someID1">stuff</div>x<div id="someID2">more stuff</div>
```

Is there a way to get that 'x' between those divs out?
It's a temp fix before permanent fix can take effect :-(

Comment: What prevents you from simply editing the HTML file and remove the character? Is it generated by some sort of web language (PHP, JSP, ASP,  Python etc...), show that code too.

Comment: already done that, but I need a quick fix for the time being, before server side changes take place, it's a long story :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do it via JS as a quick fix,  try:

```
document.getElementById('someID1').nextSibling.nodeValue= '';
```

or

```
$('#someID1')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue= '';
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/54ufr/)**

Comment: Setting the [nodeValue](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-F68D080) to `null` may work, but it's supposed to be a string so `''` (empty string) seems more suitable.

Comment: @RobG I think setting nodevalue to null should not have any issues.

Comment: that did it, but used '' instead of null, turns out ie8 displayed 'null' but behaved correctly with '' :-) So MUCH THANKS.

Comment: @vector Thats RobG :)

Comment: IE 8 to the rescue… :-)

Answer (score 3):

PSL's solution is ok but might be a bit specific. You might be better to test the node and remove all text nodes until the next element, e.g.:

```
function clearSiblingTextNodes(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);

  while (el.nextSibling && el.nextSibling.nodeType == 3) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el.nextSibling);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I thought of this way initially but then OP wanted just a quick fix (as he has already fixed that at the server) so didn't bother testing against nodetype... :)